# Is there a built-in option to run python unittests both with `__debug__=True` and `__debug__=False`?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

My package works differently according to [`__debug__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__). (IMPORTANT EDIT: some commenters strongly advise against a `__debug__`-dependent output, or even accessing `__debug__` directly at all.)
I have a unittest file for my package, that looks pretty much like [the basic example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example). All of my unittests should pass, regardless of `__debug__`'s value.

I wish to run my unittest both for the case in which `__debug__ == True` and the case in which `__debug__ == False`.

I thought about changing `__debug__`, but this is impossible, as noted [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__).
I guess I can just use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run my unittest file twice, once with `-O` and once without `-O`, but is there a built-in option to do that? If not, is there a better way (than using `subprocess`) to do that?

Comment: "My package works differently according to `__debug__`" - I hope that just means "I do more debug checks with `__debug__` on".

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have many asserts, but I now decided to also sort some output list if `__debug__`, as it is convenient for debugging, but might be very time consuming (and the order of this output list doesn't affect anything). Is this horribly wrong to do? If it is, what would you recommend to do instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of thing you should really avoid using `__debug__` for. External behavior shouldn't depend on `__debug__`. I'd consider options like doing the sort with an external tool when debugging instead of relying on the program to sort its output, or adding an extra flag for sorting.

Comment: That still holds for a package intended to be used as a dependency for other code instead of as a standalone program - the interface your code presents to clients shouldn't depend on `__debug__`. If this list you're sorting is something your code outputs to callers, it shouldn't depend on `__debug__`.

Comment: "what would you recommend to do instead?" using logging and gating complex computations behind `logger.isEnabledFor(level)`. Don't use `__debug__`, ever.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I changed my code according to your and Masklinn's suggestion. Thanks! :)   Do you think I should delete this question?